# How to structure the graph in tensorboard produced by Keras code?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorboard

*Using the functional API, is there a way to get the tensorboard graph produced from a keras code correctly structured ?*

*Is there any way for example to name a block of instructions in the functional approach at both instantiation and calling times ?*

I'm trying to get the graph of a network well structured in tensorboard.

Apparently, when using the functional API, the *tf.name_scope* is used in the graph when instantiating a model/layer, at the opposite,  the *name* kwargs is used  when calling a model/layer once already instantiate.
Moreover, tf.name_scope blocks do not appears in part of the graph corresponding to a call (they do appears in instantiation part).

The only way I have found that the same name is used at both instantiation and calling as well as having block of layers correctly structured in the graph is to  derived custom layers from base class Layer. But that it is really painfull/overkill, make the code unreadable in big models or can be infeasible for some multi-inputs/multi-outputs models.

Here is an example with an auto-encoder code.

**Example with the functional API**

```
from keras import Model
from keras import backend as K
from keras.layers import Input, Dense, ReLU

layers=[1024,512,128,64]

graph = K.tf.Graph()
with graph.as_default():

    with K.name_scope('ns_encoder'):
        x = Input(shape=(layers[0],))
        z = x
        for hu in layers[1:]:
            with K.name_scope('ns_encblock'):
                z = Dense(hu)(z)
                z = ReLU()(z)
        encoder = Model(inputs=x,outputs=z, name='m_encoder')

    with K.name_scope('ns_decoder'):
        x = Input(shape=(layers[-1],))
        z = x
        for hu in layers[:-1][::-1]:
            with K.name_scope('ns_decblock'):
                z = Dense(hu)(z)
                z = ReLU()(z)
        decoder = Model(inputs=x,outputs=z, name='m_decoder')    

    with K.name_scope('ns_ae'):
        x = Input(shape=(layers[0],))
        z = encoder(x)
        xh = decoder(z)
        ae = Model(inputs=x,outputs=xh, name='m_ae')

writer = K.tf.summary.FileWriter(logdir='logdir', graph=graph)
writer.flush()
```

[Graph produced by the functional API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lbmwy.png)

The same layer re_lu_3 appears correctly inside a block in ns_encoder but not in the "m_encoder" of "ns_ae". Moreover name_scope 'ns_encoder' is used in encoder model definition, while name kwarg 'm_encoder' is used  in model functional use in "ns_ae"

**Example with derived class**

```
from keras import Model
from keras import backend as K
from keras.layers import Input, Dense, ReLU, Layer

layers=[1024,512,128,64]

class Block(Layer):
    def __init__(self, hu, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.hu = hu
    def build(self,input_shape):
        self.dense =  Dense(self.hu)
        self.relu = ReLU()
        super().build(input_shape)
    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return self.relu.compute_output_shape(
                self.dense.compute_output_shape(input_shape))
    def call(self,x):
        return self.relu(self.dense(x))   

graph = K.tf.Graph()
with graph.as_default():

    with K.name_scope('ns_encoder'):
        x = Input(shape=(layers[0],))
        z = x
        for hu in layers[1:]:
            with K.name_scope('ns_encblock'):
                z = Block(hu)(z)
        encoder = Model(inputs=x,outputs=z, name='m_encoder')

    with K.name_scope('ns_decoder'):
        x = Input(shape=(layers[-1],))
        z = x
        for hu in layers[:-1][::-1]:
            with K.name_scope('ns_decblock'):
                z = Block(hu)(z)
        decoder = Model(inputs=x,outputs=z, name='m_decoder')

    with K.name_scope('ns_ae'):
        x = Input(shape=(layers[0],))
        z = encoder(x)
        xh = decoder(z)
        ae = Model(inputs=x,outputs=xh, name='m_ae')

writer = K.tf.summary.FileWriter(logdir='logdir', graph=graph)
writer.flush()
```

[Graph produced by the class derivation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bUPro.png)

This time the graph is correctly structured: block_3 appears on both encoder and full auto-encoder. But the code is really overkilled and this paradigm can not be applied all the time.